# PHP: Building array out of values of another, associative, multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array, let's call it $menus, that contains something like this:

```
Array(
    [Main] => Array (
        [menu_name] => Main
        [title] => Main Menu
    )
    [Nav] => Array (
        [menu_name] => Navigation
        [title] => Navigation Menu
    )
    [Custom] => Array (
        [menu_name] => User Custom Menu
        [title] => My Menu
    )
)
```

...and so forth.

I need to create a new array that contains only a list of menu names. So if I were going to get, say, just the Nav menu's name, I'd do

```
$module_menu_name = $menus [Nav][menu_name];
```

and now $module_menu_name = "Navigation", right?

But how do I get the menu_name of each item in an associative array?

Something like:

```
$menu_names = Array();
foreach($menus as $menu){
    $module_menu_names[] => ???['menu_name'];
}
```

... and this is where I get stuck. What do I put where those question marks are? Is this even the right way to build this array?

Comment: Assigning them to a new `array` is fine, but what exactly do you want to do with the `menu_names`?

Comment: I want to supply the list to a form to offer them as options for checkboxes.

Comment: this is why php needs to create a function called array_pluck(), but they dont want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$menu_names = Array();
foreach($menus as $menu){
    $menu_names[] = $menu['menu_name'];
}
```

Like this?

In your foreach, $menu returns the 2nd-level arrays. To access the 'menu_name', just get that value of the 2nd-level array and put it into your $menu_names array.

**Note:** I changed your $module_menu_names array to $menu_names, since it seemed like that's what you want to do. If not, just change $menu_names inside the foreach loop to $module_menu_names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu_names = Array();
foreach($menus as $menu){
    $menu_names[] = $menu['menu_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need this.

```
$array = array();
foreach($menus as $menu) {
    $array['nav']['menu_name'][] = $menu['menu_name'];
}
```

since there will be multiple menus in your array you can call the menus like this

```
//this will return the first menu in an array
$module_menu_name = $array['nav']['menu_name'][0];
```

change the numeric index number and you can get the desired menu from the array.